# Substring replacement inside XML values with XMLStarlet

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, cdata, xmlstarlet

I am attempting to edit/update some complex XML that I unfortunately cannot change the format of.  I am using XMLStarlet within a Bash script.

Where I am struggling, is when I attempt to retrieve or edit a CDATA value of an attribute where the attribute `"name={name}"` is not unique and returns multiple values.

For example, I have the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="key.xsl" ?>
<tables>
  <tableset>
    <table name="table1">
      <row>
        <fld name="fileName">
          <strval><![CDATA[/my/XYZ/file1]]></strval>
        </fld>
        <fld name="fileName">
          <strval><![CDATA[/my/XYZ/file2]]></strval>
        </fld>
        <fld name="fileName">
          <strval><![CDATA[/my/other/XYZ/file3]]></strval>
        </fld>
        <fld name="worksBecauseUnique">
          <strval><![CDATA[/XYZ/unique]]></strval>
        </fld>
      </row>
    </table>
  </tableset>
</tables>
```

When using XMLStarlet, I am able to easily edit the following value:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L \
  -u '//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name="worksBecauseUnique"]/strval/text()' \
  -v '/ABC/unique' \
  myxmlfile.xml
```

However, I am facing issues when trying to modify any of the CDATA values with the attribute, `name=fileName`, since `fileName` occurs more than once in the XML.

I am hoping for output like the following:

```xml
<fld name="fileName">
  <strval><![CDATA[/my/ABC/file1]]></strval>
</fld>
<fld name="fileName">
  <strval><![CDATA[/my/ABC/file2]]></strval>
</fld>
<fld name="fileName">
  <strval><![CDATA[/my/other/ABC/file3]]></strval>
</fld>
```

The problem is, if I try to update the CDATA value for `fileName` using XMLStarlet, how do I update each without updating all?

For example, if I run:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L \
  -u "//tables/tableset/table/row/fld[@name=\"fileName\"]/strval/text()" \
  -v "/my/ABC/file1" \
  myxmlfile.xml
```

I get the following incorrect output:

```xml
<fld name="fileName">
  <strval><![CDATA[/my/ABC/file1]]></strval>
</fld>
<fld name="fileName">
  <strval><![CDATA[/my/ABC/file1]]></strval>
</fld>
<fld name="fileName">
  <strval><![CDATA[/my/ABC/file1]]></strval>
</fld>
```

Notice how each CDATA value is set to `"/my/ABC/file1"` where I would need `"/my/ABC/file1"`, `"/my/ABC/file2"`, and `"/my/other/ABC/file3"`

I'm hoping to somehow allow someone to modify each value individually...
Hopefully this is possible using any tool that supports XPath.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the future, please consider including a terse, to-the-point summary of your question that's clearly set out, so one doesn't have to read a wall of text to understand what you're trying to do. To quote http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html -- volume is not precision!

Comment: Apologies... thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Provide an expression (with `-x`) that modifies your input into the output you want:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -u '//fld/strval[contains(., "/XYZ/")]' \
  -x 'concat(substring-before(., "/XYZ/"), "/ABC/", substring-after(., "/XYZ/"))'
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

Incidentally, there are better string replacement functions in newer versions of the XPath standard; as libxml (used by XMLStarlet) supports only version 1.0, the expression is a bit unwieldier than might otherwise be the case.

Comment: Thanks, this works to change a specific value and then concatenate the remainder of the string however I need to be able to modify each value within the strval field individually...

Comment: Does your question indicate that need somewhere? (See again re: being long enough that it's not entirely easy to read).